# Internet access ok on host, fails from guest unless host is using VPN

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, centos, vagrant

I have a Vagrant-provisioned CentOS guest on an Ubuntu host. Internet access from host is absolutely fine. But Internet access from guest often fails unless host is using VPN.

For example:

**Host using standard network adapter, no VPN:**

```
$ curl https://packagist.org/packages.json
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'packagist.org'
```

**Host using VPN:**

```
$ curl https://packagist.org/packages.json
{ successful-json-payload }
```

Guest networking is NAT. VirtualBox GUI showing the correct host adapter.

I live in Thailand and VPN is US-based. Ideas?

Comment: The error is telling you that DNS is not working.  What name servers have you set in the guest, and can you ping them?

Comment: @Paul: Using Google DNS: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4. Yep, can ping them from the guest. But attempting to curl (from the guest) the standard assortment of reliable sites fails with `curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host`. And still, if I connect the host to my VPN, those curls all sail through smoothly.

Comment: Strange, the dns must be getting bloked, or failing to NAT.  Your question says "often fails", does that means it works without VPN sometimes?   How about doing a `tcpdump host <guest ip> and port 53` on the host to see if the DNS queries are making it out ok.

Comment: What happens if you do a "traceroute -n 74.125.235.146" ?  This will tell us if you have a problem with outbound Internet connectivity or the DNS service.

Comment: `traceroute -n` runs clean to completion. But `traceroute` to another ping-able (!) IP dies. @Paul: IP of guest is 10.0.2.15. Ping from host to guest fails. `tcpdump` on host as suggested fails ("no suitable device found"). Thanks for all the ideas. Keep 'em coming! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You might want to configure your vagrant according to the snippet below, might have something to do with it. It was driving me nuts too!

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  # ...

  config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
end
```

source : https://gist.github.com/mitchellh/1277049

Comment: That looks like an interesting idea. I'll try it out and get back to you. Thanks! ;-)